# What is wrong with this simple code meant to decrypt with AES 256 bit key using the Windows CryptoAPI?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptoapi

I have a small program that is encrypting files using the AES-256 key. The key used to encrypt the file is generated randomly.

The encryption program goes like this:

- Acquire crypto context - `CryptAcquireContext`
- generate an AES-256 key using `CryptGenKey`
- Encrypt a file using this key -- `CryptEncrypt`
- Release cryto context -- `CryptReleaseContext`

The file encrypted is a small `test.txt` file containing the string: "just a test". And so the raw hex bytes in the file are:

```
6A 75 73 74 20 61 20 74 65 73 74
```

The AES-256 key used for encryption in hex format is:

> 3f10e23bb1a5dfd9c8ca06195e43043386a9ba4c63c35ac518f463ba768f001b

The encrypted file `test.enc` then has the bytes:

```
C8 B5 92 51 22 53 75 A1 34 80 EC AA 37 1C 6C BE
```

**Question:**

How do I write a c/c++ program to decrypt these bytes using the hex AES-256 key using the Windows CryptoAPI's `CryptDecrypt` function?

**What I have tried:**

I have written the following decryption program (a slight modification of the [gist here](https://gist.github.com/hasherezade/2860d94910c5c5fb776edadf57f0bef6).)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

#define BLOCK_LEN 128

HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    wchar_t default_key[] = L"PxDiO7Gl39nIygYZXkMEM4apukxjw1rFGPRjunaPABs";
    wchar_t* key_str = default_key;
    size_t len = lstrlenW(key_str);



    if (!CryptAcquireContext(
        &hCryptProv,
        NULL,
        MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV,
        PROV_RSA_AES,
        NULL))
    {
        /*std::cout << "error acquiring context\n";
        std::cout << GetLastErrorAsString();*/
        exit(1);
    }

    HCRYPTKEY hKey;


    wchar_t* filename = argv[1];
    wchar_t* filename2 = argv[2];

    printf("Key: %S\n", key_str);
    printf("Key len: %#x\n", len);
    printf("Input File: %S\n", filename);
    printf("Output File: %S\n", filename2);
    printf("----\n");

    HANDLE hInpFile = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
    if (hInpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Cannot open input file!\n");
        system("pause");
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("\nEncrypted file read.");

    HANDLE hOutFile = CreateFileW(filename2, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hOutFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Cannot open output file!\n");
        system("pause");
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("\nDecryption file created.");

    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;
    wchar_t info[] = L"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider";

    /*BOOL CryptDeriveKey(
        HCRYPTPROV hProv,
        ALG_ID     Algid,
        HCRYPTHASH hBaseData,
        DWORD      dwFlags,
        HCRYPTKEY * phKey
    );*/

    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    if (!CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptCreateHash failed: %x\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        system("pause");
        return dwStatus;
    }

    if (!CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)key_str, len, 0)) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptHashData Failed : %#x\n", err);
        system("pause");
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("[+] CryptHashData Success\n");

    if (!CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, 0, &hKey)) {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptDeriveKey failed: %x\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
        system("pause");
        return dwStatus;
    }
    printf("[+] CryptDeriveKey Success\n");


    const size_t chunk_size = BLOCK_LEN;
    BYTE chunk[chunk_size] = { 0 };
    DWORD out_len = 0;

    BOOL isFinal = FALSE;
    DWORD readTotalSize = 0;

    DWORD inputSize = GetFileSize(hInpFile, NULL);

    while (bResult = ReadFile(hInpFile, chunk, chunk_size, &out_len, NULL)) {
        if (0 == out_len) {
            break;
        }
        printf("\nFile read.");
        readTotalSize += out_len;
        if (readTotalSize == inputSize) {
            isFinal = TRUE;
            printf("\nFinal chunk set.\n");
        }

        printf("\n Now calling decryption routine...");
        if (!CryptDecrypt(hKey, NULL, isFinal, 0, chunk, &out_len)) {
            printf("[-] CryptDecrypt failed\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("CryptDecrypt succeeded.");

        DWORD written = 0;
        if (!WriteFile(hOutFile, chunk, out_len, &written, NULL)) {
            printf("writing failed!\n");
            break;
        }
        memset(chunk, 0, chunk_size);

    }
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);

    CloseHandle(hInpFile);
    CloseHandle(hOutFile);
    printf("Finished. Processed %#x bytes.\n", readTotalSize);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This just ends up telling me `CryptDecrypt` failed. So I'm guessing the key wasn't specified in the right format. I do not know how to use my AES-256 key in hex format to decrypt the data. The key is currently hard-coded in a `base64` format in the program but I'm guessing that's not correct.

Another thing I have done is that I have used the [CryptoTester tool](https://download.bleepingcomputer.com/demonslay335/CryptoTester.zip) to specify the AES key that I have in hex format and it is able to actually successfully decrypt the file. Also, this online decryption tool is also able to use the key to decrypt the data [as shown here](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index?key=3f10e23bb1a5dfd9c8ca06195e43043386a9ba4c63c35ac518f463ba768f001b&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=C8%20B5%2092%2051%2022%2053%2075%20A1%2034%2080%20EC%20AA%2037%201C%206C%20BE&mode=ecb&action=Decrypt&output=). So I know that I have the right hex key and everything and that the file can decrypted, but how do I rewrite my program above to correctly decrypt the file?

Note that all keys used or shown here are just examples.

How do I correct this program to actually decrypt the data successfully using the AES-256 key above?

Comment: When CryptDecrypt fails, what error does it give? Call and print GetLastError and check MSDN which error that corresponds to? Your idea of the wrong key might be correct but it's good to see what GetLastError returns first. Also can you try using CryptImportKey instead of CryptDeriveKey?

Comment: `CryptImportKey` expects the key to be in a KEYBLOB format with a proper blob header. I have looked into it, but have been unable to generate a proper KEYBLOB byte array for CryptImportKey with the raw hex string that I have.

Comment: I haven't dealt with Windows Crypto API in a long time but I remember there is a way to create a blob from the key. Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/base-provider-key-blobs#simple-key-blobs All you need to do is create that structure with your key BYTE array and algorithm id. But also did you check GetLastError from CryptDecrypt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple Demo Program**

Here is a small C program that uses your key and the encrypted data supplied with it and decrypts the original text again. I have tried to make it minimalistic.

For the sake of simplicity, it does not read the files from the file system, but defines the data in the C program as hex strings.

**Result**

When you run the program, the following output is output to the console:

```
decrypted result: 'just a test'
```

**C Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

void error(const char* what) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s failed with last error 0x%x\n", what, GetLastError());
    exit(1);
}

#define AES_KEY_SIZE 32
typedef struct {
    BLOBHEADER hdr;
    DWORD dwKeySize;
    BYTE rgbKeyData[AES_KEY_SIZE];
} AES256KEYBLOB;

BYTE *hex2byte(const char *hex) {
    int len = strlen(hex) / 2;
    BYTE* bytes = malloc(len);
    if (bytes == NULL) { 
        error("malloc");  
        return NULL; 
    }
    unsigned char val[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sscanf_s(&hex[i * 2], "%2hhx", &val);
        bytes[i] = val[0];
    }
    return bytes;
}

int main() {
    BYTE *key = hex2byte("3F10E23BB1A5DFD9C8CA06195E43043386A9BA4C63C35AC518F463BA768F001B");

    AES256KEYBLOB aes256KeyBlob;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.reserved = 0;
    aes256KeyBlob.hdr.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_256;
    aes256KeyBlob.dwKeySize = AES_KEY_SIZE;
    memcpy(aes256KeyBlob.rgbKeyData, key, AES_KEY_SIZE);

    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    if (!CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        error("CryptAcquireContext");
    }

    HCRYPTKEY hKey;
    if (!CryptImportKey(hProv, (BYTE*)& aes256KeyBlob, sizeof(AES256KEYBLOB), 0, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        error("CryptImportKey");
    }

    const char *encodedHex = "C8B59251225375A13480ECAA371C6CBE";
    DWORD numBytes = strlen(encodedHex) / 2;
    BYTE *encoded = hex2byte(encodedHex);

    if (CryptDecrypt(hKey, 0, TRUE, 0, encoded, &numBytes)) {
        printf("decrypted result: '");
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
            printf("%c", encoded[i]);
        }
        printf("'\n");
    } else {
        CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        error("CryptDecrypt");
    }


    free(key);
    free(encoded);

    CryptDestroyKey(hKey); 
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Microsoft Docs**

The KEYBLOB struct is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/jj650836(v%3Dvs.85)

whereas here you will find information about the BLOBHEADER structure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/ns-wincrypt-publickeystruc

Comment: Thank you! What did you compile this in? Building it in Visual Studio 2019 is giving me errors: `'BOOL CryptDecrypt(HCRYPTKEY,HCRYPTHASH,BOOL,DWORD,BYTE *,DWORD *)': cannot convert argument 6 from 'int *' to 'DWORD *`

Comment: Another error: `'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned char *'`

Comment: Do you use C or C++ in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 16.0.3 - will update and try again later. Make sure you use a C file (file suffix .c) and not C++.

Comment: Whoops. Compiled it using the C compiler. Works now!

Comment: Read Microsoft API Documents and solve your problem with an real example in GitHub projects:
https://github.com/panahiehsancom/AESWinAPI